# How create seprate tables for each entry?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table 1:

```
2020-06-26 07:58:51 ButtonA0Disabled
2020-06-26 16:47:03 ButtonA1Disabled
2020-06-26 07:58:46 ButtonA2Disabled
2020-06-26 07:58:48 ButtonA3Disabled
2020-06-26 07:58:49 ButtonA4Disabled
```

First column is time and Second is Button information!!
I have a work flow log as table!!It has Schema  (AppNAme,ButtonClicked,date,time)

```
App1,ExitApp,2020/6/26,7:55:34,
App2,Button1,2020/6/26,7:55:37,
App2,Button5,2020/6/26,7:55:42,
App2,Button7,2020/6/26,7:55:44,
App2,Button3,2020/6/26,7:56:20,
```

I want to make separate table for each row in table1. Which will show the buttons which were pressed before that particular disabled button was pressed!!

For example when ButtonA0Disabled is clicked I want make separate table which have data from workflow log that which buttons were pressed before clicking of that button.Alternatively , I want to get data from workflow log from the  to 1 or 2 minutes before   time disabled button was clicked to the time when it was clicked!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create one to many relationships structure. table 1 will have info about the button and 2nd table will have info about the button activities. 2nd table will have Foreign key of 1st table.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rather do a `SELECT` where you fetch all rows of your second table which have a timestamp before the disable event:

```
SELECT * FROM work_flow_log AS wf 
WHERE wf.ButtonClicked="ButtonA0"
  AND wf.dateTime < (
    SELECT table1.dateTime FROM table1
    WHERE table1.ButtonClicked="ButtonA0Disabled"
    LIMIT 1
  );
```

Note, that this would require a modification to your tables because I'm using a combined DateTime format rather than separate columns for date and time.